# Constraining foreign keys to two parent tables

Tags: database-design

[image: example]

For the model above I want to make it so a robot must have a power supply and motor with matching voltages.  Is there a way to constrain the robot entity so it cannot have a power supply and motor that don't match voltages? Or is there a better way to model this so I don't need a constraint?

Comment: Side note:  Unless you need name to be the key, you could have a compound key over motor and power_supply to ensure that you don't have two entries for the same two parts.  If you had a Parts table, you could have a part_type column and a constraint on INSERT into robots which could require voltage to be the same across parts.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the definitive answer for which I can't take credit. That belongs to [ypercube](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/993/ypercube) who has given me an insight into the power of `FOREIGN KEY`s with multiple fields. I've taken the liberty of removing most of the previous discussion - it can be followed through the edits.

My first (primitive) answer would have worked, but the `DDL` below is so much more elegant - it's like comparing the Lascaux cave paintings with Van Gogh's masterpieces.

Definitive `DDL/DML` with `test` (using `MySQL`).

Power supply table.

```
CREATE TABLE power_supply
(
  part_no INT PRIMARY KEY,
  weight INT,
  voltage INT,
  UNIQUE(part_no, voltage)
);
```

Motor table.

```
CREATE TABLE motor
(
  part_no INT PRIMARY KEY,
  model VARCHAR(45),
  voltage INT,
  UNIQUE (part_no, voltage)
);
```

Robot table.

```
CREATE TABLE robot
(
  name VARCHAR(30) PRIMARY KEY,
  power_supply INT,
  motor INT,
  voltage INT,
  FOREIGN KEY (power_supply, voltage)
        REFERENCES power_supply (part_no, voltage),
  FOREIGN KEY (motor, voltage)
        REFERENCES motor (part_no, voltage)
);
```

DML.

```
INSERT INTO power_supply VALUES(1, 25, 10);
INSERT INTO power_supply VALUES(2, 25, 10);
INSERT INTO power_supply VALUES(3, 15, 15);
INSERT INTO power_supply VALUES(4, 25, 15);
INSERT INTO power_supply VALUES(5, 25, 15);
INSERT INTO power_supply VALUES(6, 25, 20);
INSERT INTO power_supply VALUES(7, 25, 20);
INSERT INTO power_supply VALUES(8, 25, 25);

INSERT INTO motor VALUES(1, 'Model Name', 10);
INSERT INTO motor VALUES(2, 'Model Name', 10);
INSERT INTO motor VALUES(3, 'Model Name', 15);
INSERT INTO motor VALUES(4, 'Model Name', 15);
INSERT INTO motor VALUES(5, 'Model Name', 20);
INSERT INTO motor VALUES(6, 'Model Name', 20);
INSERT INTO motor VALUES(7, 'Model Name', 25);
```

Test.

```
INSERT INTO robot VALUES('Robo Name', 2, 6, 15); -- Voltages don't match, update fails
INSERT INTO robot VALUES('Robo Name', 2, 2, 10); -- Voltages match, update succeeds
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31827/discussion-between-ypercube-and-verace).